# How to implement the One-Hot Encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I was doing some machine learing exercices, some data has qualitative variables, like sex:male, female.

When build the model, we know the qualitative variables should be set to numbers, like male to 1 and female to 0.

But this is not good enough, because the model always treats the numbers as continuous numbers, however, the factors are not continuous, they are discrete. Like 1>0, it does not mean male>female.

So we set male to 01, female to 10, by using the One-Hot Encoding.

For example, the code from the scikit-learn official website:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
>>> X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
>>> enc.fit(X)
... 
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=None, categories=None,
       dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='ignore',
       n_values=None, sparse=True)

>>> enc.categories_
[array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)]
>>> enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 4]]).toarray()
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
array([['Male', 1],
       [None, 2]], dtype=object)
>>> enc.get_feature_names()
array(['x0_Female', 'x0_Male', 'x1_1', 'x1_2', 'x1_3'], dtype=object)
```

According to this code, let's say the original Pandas Dataframe(tran_data2) may like this:

```
      Sex  ProductID  Age  Result
0    male          1   25       1
1  female          2   21       0
2  female          3   23       1
```

We now know that:

```
Sex

male:01

female:10

ProductID

1:100

2:010

3:001
```

So the ['Female', 1]=[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.] for example.
But how to use these encoded codes?
Does this mean I should transfer the original Dataframe to the format like(tran_data1):

```
   x0_Female  x0_Male  x1_1  x1_2  x1_3  Age  Result
0          0        1     1     0     0   25       1
1          1        0     0     1     0   21       0
2          1        0     0     0     1   23       1
```

Then start to build the model by using the new Dataframe?

For example,

```
from sklearn import tree
features1=['x0_Female', 'x0_Male', 'x1_1', 'x1_2', 'x1_3', 'Age']
features2=['Sex', 'ProductID', 'Age']
y_pred=list()
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(tran_data1[features1],tran_data1['Result'])
#clf.fit(tran_data2[features2],tran_data2['Result'])
y_pred=clf.predict(test_data[features1])
```

Does this mean I should use features1 instead of features2?

Comment: These values, represented now as one-hot vectors, are used as inputs or outputs to your algorithm. What are you trying to do? Which Architecture you using?

Comment: For example, I want to use Decision Tree, should I train the model by using the new factors "x0_Female, x0_Male, x1_1, x1_2, x1_3, Age" instead of "Sex , ProductID, Age"?